# test method accept other subclass as parameter

Tags: java

I worte a code:

```
package coding;

public class scanner{


static void test(a b){

    System.out.println("hello");

}
public static void main(String args[]){


    a A = null;
    b B = null;
    test(A);
    test(B);
    System.out.println(b.b);


    }

}

class a{


static int b = 10;


}
class b extends a{

    int a = 10;


}
```

I want to ask that why is the test method accept the class b instance B as a parameter.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should learn OO and see how it is used in Java. This is some basic knowledge that you should learn properly in a guide/course/tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `class b extends a` makes b to a subclass of a, that means you can use it like an instance of `a`.

Comment: So a subclass extends a superclass and the subclass instance is a superclass instance?

Comment: Exactly, because a subclass has inherited all fields and methods that belong to the superclass and normally defines just some further features.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: If your Problem is solved you can accept the best answer so others can see that your Problem is solved